# Can a single method (functional) interface have a default method?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I recently found that the following interface:

```
   public static interface LoggImpl{
        public default void Log(String s){

        }
    }
```

Cannot be referenced as a lambda:

```
// compile error: "no target method found"
static LoggImpl impl = (String s)-> {
    System.out.println(s);
};
```

Does this mean that we can't define default functionality for a single function lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN define default methods for a SAM interface, but you MUST define one and only one abstract method other than methods from the Object class: [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)

So you define a SAM with one abstract method (no default, not found in Object class signature), then as many default methods (with different signatures) as you want.